# нужно скопировать файл через cmd windows

Tags: java

есть файл находящийся в директории c://users//%user%//Desktop файл  w1.jar, его с помощью команды (copy w1.jar C:\Users\%UserName%)  можно переместить в эту директорию, но он не видет сам файл w1.jar, т.к нужно зайти через cmd в Desktop. я пытался, добавить cd Desktop, но ничего не происходит, пользуюсь я

```
Process process2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c  copy Vola2.jar C:\\Users\\%UserName% ");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А абсолютный путь не работает?
Что-то типо:

```
Process process2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c  copy c:\\users\\%user%\\Desktop\\Vola2.jar C:\\Users\\%UserName%\\Vola2.jar");
```

и вроде бы в синтаксисе команды copy нужно указывать результат вплоть до имени файла, а не только директорию.

Возможно я не правильно понял ваш вопрос, уточните, если это не подходит.

Comment: все скопировалось, спасибо вам